# Adding routes dynamically to pyramid

Tags: python, plugins, pyramid

I'd like to know how to edit pyramid registry at runtime. Well i'm not so sure exactly what I have to edit.

I know I can extend pyramid with config.include(...). But once config.make_wsgi_app() is called, there seems to be no way to add routes or new mako directories. Any change to the registery in threadlocals or settings have no effect on how the app behave.

My goal is to add plugin at runtime. Here's a use case.

Someone install my appserver running pyramid...then install some plugins

pip install page_plugin

then in /configs

There is a list of installed plugins and you can select which ones are activated or not. Currently I know of only one way to do that:

Using entry_points I can see my plugins and in the main function of pyramid, I can register the plugins. Using a filestorage I could check every plugins states: [install, installed, uninstall, uninstalled, disabled]

That way I can from a view install/uninstall my plugins.

In order to see any change I have to reboot the server.

states
    install : will install on next boot
    installed: is installed and active
    uninstall: will uninstall on next boot
    uninstalled: is uninstalled
    disabled: not uninstalled but not activated

install/uninstall are used to setup the database if needed

I think there is no real other way to do that since there is no "remove_view". I could probably make the server reload. And it would load the new configuration.

[EDIT]

There is no function to remove route or antyhing. SO my guess is that realoding the server is probably the easies and simplest way to do it... and it is probably cleaner to reboot the server than forgetting to unload some stuffs from the plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to modify the registry at runtime:

```
config = Configurator(registry=request.registry)
config.add_route(...)
config.commit()
```

You have to note, however, that modifying the registry is not a thread-safe operation. You would have to synchronize this yourself. Instead of doing this, I would suggest thinking about your problem in a different way and attempting to create routes that encompass the features that you anticipate extending. Routes can accept patterns (even `.*` if you want the rest of the URL), and there is also traversal which is very very dynamic and easy to extend at runtime.

Adding removable views is possible, but I wouldn't do it at the "adding or removing of routes" level. Instead I suggest using custom predicates on your routes that control whether the route is matched or not.

```
def is_enabled(info, request):
    return True if route_should_be_enabled else False

config.add_route('my_plugin_head', '/foo/{bar}', custom_predicates=[is_enabled])
```

In this way, if is_enabled returns False, the route is never matched and is effectively ignored.

Comment: It is really interesting, i'll have to get a look to that and i'll come up with some result I guess.

Comment: Seems to work pretty well thanks, I'm using traversal currently on one project since I use zodb and it feels likes its really the only logical way to do it. I have other project with mongodb that currently define their own routes but I believe I can achieve the same result with traversal. Coming from pylons I got really used to routes and got scared by the magic behind traversal

Comment: I still only have a question, when you say that editing the registry isn't thread safe. You mean that if two people are editing the registry it will fail or unfortunately have some unexpected result.

will have to look how it's done but I see two possibilities. Configurator copy config and then push it to the registry and overwrite it completely. Or push only new or modified configs. My guess it overwrite. So if someone does an edit while someone is editing it. The changes might never be saved. I don't think its a big deal for now but good to keep in mind.

Comment: I'm saying that the registry is the core of pyramid. It contains a ton of shared state that is read-only between all of the threads that are serving requests. If you mess with that state, it could cause problems with another thread(request) and while it may work, there are absolutely no guarantees that it will.